# How to enforce maven build to fail if the version number is not matching from changes.xml

Tags: maven, pom.xml, maven-plugin

Folks,

I need some inputs, in order to enforce a validation check during the maven build.

My maven build should only be built successfully, only when the version of pom (say 1.1-SNAPSHOT) is matching with the latest version from changes.xml (release version=1.1)

Any input would be helpful. Is there any way we can achieve this?

Thanks!